# How can I count the row number in the returned group of mysql query?

Tags: mysql

How can I get the row number in the returned mysql query? Let say, if my query is returning some 5 rows as a result, I want to know that row is 1st,2nd, 3rd etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, t.*
FROM some_table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```